# AWS S3 REST API "RequestTimeTooSkewed" Error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3

I am attempting to initiate a multipart upload to an s3 bucket directly from the browser by following the corresponding [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/api-multipart-initiate-upload.html). However, I'm receiving the following response error:

```
<Error>
   <Code>RequestTimeTooSkewed</Code>
   <Message>The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.</Message>
   <RequestTime>20210105T044520315Z</RequestTime>
   <ServerTime>2021-01-05T04:45:21Z</ServerTime>
   <MaxAllowedSkewMilliseconds>900000</MaxAllowedSkewMilliseconds>
   <RequestId>1CB4A7412B51D</RequestId>
   <HostId>Hb2KatQA+Liv8lfWLW73dRyPUyCjJez/qwelRyV52r8cd2qXR5dBSpPY=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Am I mistaken or are these times in fact within the 9000 millisecond skew cap in which AWS deems a request time valid?

After console logging the times for better analysis - I can in-fact confirm the discrepancy between client and server times are less than 9000 milliseconds.

```
**AWS server time** 2021-01-05T04:45:21.000Z

**Client server time** 2021-01-05T04:45:20.544Z
```

Am I missing something trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was due to `RequestTime` not being in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), since the format does not use miliseconds. The [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-date-handling.html) also write:

> Do not include milliseconds in the time stamp.